# Javascript changing a specific element in a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have something like this in my html:

```
<div id="basket">
    <div id="item">Apple</div>
</div>
<div id="basket">
    <div id="item">Orange</div>
</div>
<div id="basket">
    <div id="item">Banana</div>
</div>
// And so on
```

How would I be able to change the innerHTML of each 'item' div individually?
For example, how would I change the div that says 'banana' to something else?

Comment: First, I think that the id values should be unique. If you assigned unique Id values, then you can find them in JavaScript with document.getElementById(“<your id value>”

Comment: Your question is broad and vague. Please be way more specific. Also depends on more factors. Is Banana the only content of the div or is it within a text or child elements?

Comment: Let’s say that unique id values are impossible. You should be using the “class” attribute the way you are using “id” above.  If you had <div class=“item”> then you can use the getElementsByClassName(“item”) to get all of the item elements. Then you can test each with if (el.innerText == “banana”) { el.innerText = “no fruit for you!”; }

Comment: @MikeWodarczyk I would rather advise `querySelectorAll` and `forEach` which is more efficient and returns a Node-List rather then a HTMLcollection Object.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned within the comments, an ID has to be unique so you have to change them to classes.

Then to solve your issue, you can use `querySelectorAll` to select all elements with the class `item`. Then you sue the `forEach`-loop and check the innerHTML of every Element. if it matches "Banana" you can rewrite the innerHTML (should use `textContent` though for security reasons):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.item').forEach(el =>  {
  if (el.textContent == 'Banana') {
    el.textContent = 'The Minions ate the Banana';
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="basket">
  <div class="item">Apple</div>
</div>
<div class="basket">
  <div class="item">Orange</div>
</div>
<div class="basket">
  <div class="item">Banana</div>
</div>
```